# Exclude modules while building OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

Is it possible to build OpenCV, including only the object detection module and excluding everything else ?

Comment: I suggest you go to the OpenCV forums to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, `objdetect` depends on other OpenCV's libs, i.e. `core`, `imgproc`, `highgui`.

You can use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find the minimal subset of necessary libs.